# SQL Server - Dynamic Averages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table that tracks total purchases by a single person and then dynamically adds columns for each category of purchase and how many purchases within each category. This table is dynamically created in the sense that it reads in the input table and will split out each category into different columns, but I don't know the categories ahead of time. So like below:

[image]

Is there a way I can dynamically rank each person based on how distributed their purchases are? For example I would expect to see person 5 at the bottom because they only purchased electronics. I would then expect person 1 to be towards the top because they have a fairly even spread of purchases for each category. I hope this question makes sense haha.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One method uses the sum of the absolute values of the differences from 1/3:

```
order by ( abs( (1.0 / 3) - (food * 1.0 / total) ) +
           abs( (1.0 / 3) - (clothes * 1.0 / total) ) +
           abs( (1.0 / 3) - (electronics * 1.0 / total) )
         )
```

Someone who has their purchases spread exactly the same among the three categories would have a score of `0`.  Someone who had all purchases in the same group would have the maximum score of `2/3`.

Note:  There are zillions of other options.  Another option would be to square the values rather than taking the absolute value.  Technically, the above uses Manhattan distance from the expected value; the square would be the Euclidian distance (well the square thereof).